# Search and get all parents that contains a child with value

Tags: grails, groovy

```
class Client {
    String name
    static hasMany = [courses:Course]
}

class Course {
    String name
    static belongsTo = [client:Client]
}
```

I have this and I want to get all **Clients** that has a **Course** with **name** = "blabla"

I was trying to do : Clients.findWhere(Course.any { course -> course.name = "math" })

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with criteria:

```
Client.withCriteria {
  courses {
    eq('name', 'math')
  }
}
```

I believe that the following where query is equivalent to the above criteria:

```
Client.where { courses.name == 'math' }
```

or you may find you need another closure:

```
Client.where {
  courses {
    name == 'math'
  }
}
```

but I rarely use where queries myself so I'm not 100% sure of that.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a lot of different syntactical expressions to achieve the same thing.  I can say definitively that this works in my project though.

```
def ls = Client.list {
    courses {
        eq('name','math')
    }
}
```

Comment: it return an error "No signature of method: Test.Client.list() is applicable for argument" .. where instead of list works fine for me and I'm using Grails 2.1.0